# String.h Errors From g++ Compilation

Tags: c++, string, g++, compiler-errors

I cannot make heads or tails of the following C++ error generated by g++

```
/tmp/ccH0IPVU.o: In function `myAPP::mandatory_bitfield_t::to_s(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
myAPP.cpp:(.text._ZN3myAPP20mandatory_bitfield_t4to_sERSsSs[myAPP::mandatory_bitfield_t::to_s(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)]+0x8c): undefined reference to `myAPP::to_s(unsigned char*, int)'
/tmp/ccH0IPVU.o: In function `myAPP::optional_bitfield_t::to_s(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
myAPP.cpp:(.text._ZN3myAPP19optional_bitfield_t4to_sERSsSs[myAPP::optional_bitfield_t::to_s(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)]+0x8d): undefined reference to `myAPP::to_s(unsigned char*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what these errors are in reference to and how I can fix them?

Comment: You could provide a code snippet from the `myAPP.cpp` file.

Comment: Do you have a `myAPP::to_s(unsigned char*, int)`? If yes, check whether you're passing the necessary object file to the linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the linker knows, you have forgotten to include (compile) a definition of `myAPP::to_s(unsigned char*, int)`.

I'm just translating the error message.

Cheers & hth.

Comment: Further, that undefined function is being invoked from `myAPP::mandatory_bitfield_t::to_s(std::string)` and `myAPP::optional_bitfield_t::to_s(std::string)`.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually a linker error.

```
undefined reference to `myAPP::to_s(unsigned char*, int)
```

means that your code is *calling* the `to_s` method somewhere, but the body of this method was not included in the object files passed to the linker.